# Get all locations a menu is assigned to

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to conditionally show information in the wordpress admin based on what locations a menu has been added to.  So to achieve this I must be able to get all locations assigned to a nav menu but I am really struggling to find out how.

When a menu is created it creates and entry for that menu in `wp_terms` and a taxonomy entry of `nav_menu` associated to this term in `wp_term_taxonomy`.  When an item is created on that menu it creates a post of type `nav_menu_item`.  It also creates and entry in `wp_term_relationships` linking it to the correct `nav_menu`.

Where does it save the menu location?

I have checked `wp_postmeta`, `wp_termmeta` and `wp_options` but I cannot see it.  I cannot figure out any way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

`get_nav_menu_locations()` sets the array key to the ID of the menu.  This code worked for me:

```
    $locations      = get_registered_nav_menus();
    $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

    $nav_menu_selected_id = isset( $_REQUEST['menu'] ) ? (int) $_REQUEST['menu'] : 0;

    $selected_menus = array();

    foreach($locations as $location => $description){
        $checked = isset( $menu_locations[ $location ] ) && $menu_locations[ $location ] === $nav_menu_selected_id;

        if($checked) $selected_menus[] = $location;
    }
```